# Sharepoint site deleted and removed by Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email

A client of mine had a problem as follows:

She did a website scanning on one of her SharePoint Site using the Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner (http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm). After the scan was half way thru, she receive many spam email.

After seeing so much spam email. She stop the Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner and went for her tea break. When she come back, her SharePoint Site that she perform her scanning was gone ("vanish / do not exist").

She asked me if it is possible to have a SharePoint Site deleted by a 3rd party scanning software. Therefore, I would like to ask on behalf of her to all the SharePoint expert out there if such possibilities is possible and are there ways to prevent it or trace if it is the Scanner who cause such chaos.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question to ask Acunetix? Looks like it did the job and found some vulnerabilities...

Comment: Have direct my client to them but imo, I think would be better for me to share this question here as it would benefit the community as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scan may have raised notifications, such as emails, which explains the spamming of users with the scan.

There may be a threshold set which has turned off your SharePoint website to prevent the spam continuing.

Check in IIS that the website and application pool is started.

Otherwise check the ULS logs for any delete commands etc.

Comment: Hi Russell, is it possible to let me know where can I find this threshold set that I can use to prevent the spam continuing?

Comment: You can turn off notifications in web application general settings in central administration.

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude this directory from scanning because it has an option to delete the entire Sharepoint site.

*/Deleteweb.aspx